# Why does binding variables to an event listener callback cause it to be defined again? Can this be avoided?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, addeventlistener

Apologies if this is a bit rough, I'm relatively new to React. This may even be more of a JavaScript question.

I'm trying to add an event listener that will trigger a callback inside a component. This component can appear on the page multiple times, and with the code below, when `#btn` is clicked the `console.log` will be output once - I can add as many `<MyComponent />` as I like, and the log will only ever be output once - as required.

```js
const callback = (e) => {
  console.log('callback happened!!', e.type);
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  if (btn) {
    const name = 'Bob';
    btn.addEventListener('click', callback);
  }
    return (
    <div>
      <p>Hi from my component!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <MyComponent />
       <p>...</p>
       <MyComponent />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="btn">button</div>
```

The problem I'm getting is if I try passing a variable (`name`) to the callback function using bind (eg `btn.addEventListener('click', callback.bind(null, name));`), when I click the button, the output will be logged **twice** - not what I want to happen! I need the `name` variable and the event object to be available in the `callback` function.

I should clarify that in the example above I am using a click listener on the button, but the real-world case will be listening for an event emitted from something else.

I have tried moving the callback function into the `App` class, and passing it as a prop to the component, but the same thing happens - as soon as I bind a variable to it, it triggers the console log twice.

So, my questions are, why does this happen? How can these requirements be achieved?

All suggestions welcome, and thanks!

Comment: `btn.addEventListener('click', callback);` will be called as many times as MyComponent is rendered. Hence you are having multiple listeners on btn. Idk your use case, but it looks like you should have a singleton approach or some approach where there is persistence. Also you might want to share your real use case

Comment: *"...but the real-world case will be listening for an event emitted from something else..."* Should all instances of your component react to the event?

Comment: Note that you're adding the same function reference multiple times when you render your function component, so only one event listener is added (as it's the same function reference, this is why you see one log). When you use `.bind()` you create a new function each time, causing both logs to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said the button is a stand-in for a different kind of event source, so we won't worry about the fact that attaching a click handler like this isn't how you would normally do this in React. I'm going to assume the other event source is outside the React tree.

Your component function is called *every time* the component needs to be rendered, which can be multiple times. Your code is adding a handler every time the function runs. When you do that using `callback` directly, it's the same function every time so it doesn't get added (because `addEventListener` doesn't add the same function for the same event to the same event target more than once, even if you call it repeatedly). But when you use `bind`, you're creating a **new** function every time, and so `addEventListener` adds those new functions on every render.

Instead, do the set up only when the component is mounted. Also, remove it when the component is unmounted. You can do that via [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect):

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        if (btn) {
            const name = "Bob";
            const handler = callback.bind(null, name);
            // Or: `const handler = (event) => callback(name, event);`
            btn.addEventListener("click", handler);
            return () => {
                // This function is called to clean up
                btn.removeEventListener("click", handler);
            };
        }
    }, []); // <== Empty array means "only on mount"
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hi from my component!</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```js
const { useEffect } = React;

const callback = (name, e) => {
    console.log(`Callback happened!! type = ${e.type}, name = ${name}`);
};

const MyComponent = ({ name }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`MyComponent "${name}": Mounted`);
        const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        if (btn) {
            // Using a prop here instead of a constant so we can tell each
            // component instance is calling the callback
            const handler = callback.bind(null, name);
            // Or: `const handler = (event) => callback(name, event);`
            btn.addEventListener("click", handler);
            return () => {
                // This function is called to clean up
                btn.removeEventListener("click", handler);
            };
        }
    }, []); // <== Empty array means "only on mount"
    console.log(`MyComponent "${name}": Rendering`);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hi from my component! name = {name}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

// Note: The React team considedr `class` components "legacy;" new code should use function components
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 0,
        };
    }

    render() {
        const increment = () =>
            this.setState(({ counter }) => ({ counter: counter + 1 }));
        const { counter } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    Click the counter to see that the handler isn't added on
                    every render: {counter}{" "}
                    <input type="button" value="+" onClick={increment} />
                </div>
                <MyComponent name="first" />
                <p>...</p>
                <MyComponent name="second" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="button">
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're correct in your assumption! Thanks for the answer, that's all great information - I'll definitely be exploring the use of useEffect today. As for components mounting/unmounting, I'm still a bit confused about this and need to do some reading... This is definitely a pointer in the right direction though! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are creating the event listener when your component gets created, but you're never deleting it. This means that each time you instantiate the component, a new event listener is created, and so a new console.log will be displayed.

Furthermore, you are doing things in a strange way:

1. Don't use React Class Components, Functional components are the recommended  choice;
2. Why are you creating the button with an id and then getting the button reference inside of the component? The advantage of React is the fact that you don't have to do this, but you just insert the component where the `<div id="btn">button</div>` is.

I will propose you two solutions to this problem, the first one using Class Components, in order to be closer to your solution (even though it's not recommended to use them anymore) and one with functional components:

Class Components:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    handleClick = (name, e) => {
        console.log("callback happened!!", e.type, name)
    }

    render() {
        const { name } = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <p onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(name, e)}>Hi from my component!</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent name="Bob" />
                <p>...</p>
                <MyComponent name="Alice" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Functional Components:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

function MyComponent({ name }) {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log("callback happened!!", e.type, name)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>Hi from my component!</p>
        </div>
    )
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <MyComponent name="Bob" />
            <p>...</p>
            <MyComponent name="Alice" />
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Note that in both the solutions I don't explicitly create the event listener, but I attach the callback function that has to be invoked on click inside the `onClick` property of the element.

If, on the other hand, you are obliged to add the event listener, then you it's important to remove it when the components unmount.

Class Components:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const callback = (name) => (e) => {
  console.log('callback happened!!', e.type, name);
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    if (btn) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', callback(this.props.name));
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    if (btn) {
      btn.removeEventListener('click', callback(this.props.name));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hi from my component!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyComponent name="Bob" />
        <p>...</p>
        <MyComponent name="Alice" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Functional Components:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const callback = (name) => (e) => {
  console.log('callback happened!!', e.type, name);
};

function MyComponent(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    if (btn) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', callback(props.name));

      return () => {
        btn.removeEventListener('click', callback(props.name));
      };
    }
  }, [props.name]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hi from my component!</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent name="Bob" />
      <p>...</p>
      <MyComponent name="Alice" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Hope this is useful!

Comment: This is great, and definitely food for though, thank you. Yep, sorry it was just a rough example from a JS fiddle - the structure is a bit rubbish but it was just for a rough idea. 
I have heard a few people mention that functional components are better than classy components now - do you know of any good reads on this subject?

Comment: See the official docs: [React: Component](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component) which begins with a note stating *”We recommend defining components as functions instead of classes.”*